# From Twitter API 1.0 to 1.1, gtm-oauth fails to authenticate correctly

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth

So, I naively switched my endpoint paths to 1.1/ to see if it would work while using the gtm-oauth library, which has been working fine.

It seems to have broken in the switch.  I've received confirmation that the authentication is much stricter (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12322) and some suggestions for debugging. Evidently the new API is too strict for the current gtm-oauth.

**Q:** I wonder if anyone has used gtm-oauth against the new Twitter API? And, if so — what did you do to get it to work?

I'll continue to debug, but in the meantime, I thought I'd ask and perhaps save myself some time and hassles.

Here's what I've done to determine what may be wrong from my side.

I've looked closely at my Authentication headers which — except for oauth_nonce and oauth_signature (and timestamp), are consistent between my app and the OAuth Signing Tool.

It seems to me that either the signing mechanics have altered, or the nonce uniqueness requirements have changed between 1.0 and 1.1.

The error I get back from the service is:

> "Bad Authentication data","code":215" for: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=darthjulian&count=2

using the following authentication parameters in the request header:

> OAuth oauth_consumer_key="09ARKva0K7HMz1DW1GUg",
>   oauth_token="185383-nxvJMkTAvYX14YRdBhEOfOUKYzcA3ZQzLqNVMMt4Nc",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0",
>   oauth_nonce="e4ad7f4753c4929", oauth_timestamp="1352098450",
>   oauth_signature="hA9s%2B%2FnGRUc9OdUNqf5G4cQn5g0%3D"

a few moments later, the OAuth signing tool told me I should be using something like this:

> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="09ARKva0K7HMz1DW1GUg",
>   oauth_nonce="3a2881b92c790e41cf6e211124f1e099",
>   oauth_signature="OlN0h3vPdPih8F%2FQbEDQth5RVZQ%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1352098650",
>   oauth_token="185383-nxvJMkTAvYX14YRdBhEOfOUKYzcA3ZQzLqNVMMt4Nc",
>   oauth_version="1.0"

Aside from the oauth_timestamp nonce and the signature are the only things that are off. And, if I understand things correctly, nonce should be okay so long as its likely to be unique for awhile.

Seems like the signing mechanics are different and I should change how GTM-OAuth signs?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I'm revisiting an app I've had on the back burner for a while (started it back when Twitter API 1.0 was all the rage) and am having a very similar problem.